# Build array from other random arrays elements in a for loop in Javascrypt

Tags: javascript

If we want  to build a phrase using random words of arrays, we could use

```
part_0=["Hello",....]
part_1=["I am",.....]

phrase=part_0[Math.round(Math.random() *(part_0.length-1))]+part_1[Math.round(Math.random() *
(part_1.length-1))]+...+part_n[Math.round(Math.random() *(part_n.length-1))]
```

But as you se above this will take too long for  a n number of words, so instead of that fat part i tried to build the phrase with a for loop.
The problem here is that in the for loop, part_i is read plain text, and not as part_number(i)

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < 3; _i++) {
  phrase.add(part_i);
};
```

Any idea to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered an array of arrays instead of individual variables for each array? There is no dynamic way to access a variable name unless it is an object property

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is an *array* of those arrays:

```js
function pickRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

let sections = [
    ["Hello,", "Hi,", "Howdy!", "Hey,"],
    ["I am", "You are", "They are", "We are"],
    ["making", "building", "crafting", "decorating"],
    ["a tower", "a machine", "a table", "a chair"],
    ["with", "using", "gluing", "consisting of"],
    ["toilet paper", "plastic cups", "paper clips", "staples"]
];

let phrase = sections.map(pickRandom).join(" ");

console.log(phrase);
```